# JBoss - implementing a application specific valve

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jboss6.x

How can we configure a Valve for a particular web application in jboss AS 6?

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  This question isn't clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an easy way to create valves in an application specific way. For most purposes you can use a servlet filter that can easily go into a .war archive.

Answer (score 1):

Valves are usually configured in the Tomcat `server.xml` or `context.xml` file.

You can configure a context.xml specifically for your web application by creating a `META-INF/context.xml` file inside your WAR. Note that for it to work, you must not have a `<Context>` element for your application in the global Tomcat context.xml.

Then in your `META-INF/context.xml` just configure your specific Valve(s) for your application:

```
<Context path="/mycontext">
    <Valve className="com.example.MyValve" />
</Context>
```

Useful reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context and http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Request_Filters